# How often do stars form?

Tags: star, universe, space-time

There are many more stars in the universe than the years that the universe has been in existence, so wouldn't this mean that stars were/are forming at an astounding rate?

Comment: It depends, on where and when. You should constrain a bit your question. Also the very first statement is not clear to me.

Comment: That depends on your definition of what is an `astounding rate`.

Answer (score 4):

By an estimated order of magnitude there are about $10^{22}$ in our observable universe ([hundred billion galaxies with hundred billion stars, each, as a rough estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Extrapolation_from_number_of_stars)), and the [universe exits since](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_universe) (order of magnitude) $10^{10}$ years. Hence the average formation rate of stars has been about $10^{12}$ per year, meaning more than 10,000 per second, give or take a factor of 100. This calculation ignores stars which don't exist any more, but for an order-of-magnitude estimate numbers should be ok.

Although the star formation rate has been much higher in the younger universe than today. ([One of the press releases](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/herschel/news/herschel20130417.html#.U2oKMYF_uqg) about star formation in the early universe)